# How to add products with price as "Contact for Pricing" in magento

Tags: magento, product

I have a Magento site.

I have a number of products to add.

```
But some have price as "Contact for Pricing" or "Call for Pricing" so cant to add.

Because there has validation for the price.
```

So how can I add such products?

If there is any module for such products?

I need to display such product's price as "Contact for Pricing" or "Call for Pricing".

if there is an extension for "call for price" download free?

Comment: If there is no extension for this, it is not too hard to do yourself I think.

Comment: This type of question doesn't really belong on Stack Overflow, as it's not a programming question. You should take a look at http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/25439/magento and see about getting a proper place to put these kind of questions

Answer (score 4):

Josh's answer slightly improved. Thanks Josh for the Idea of using attributes!

Create the attribute code 'call_4_price' for this example. Like Josh suggested, make it a Yes/No attribute. Default Value "No". Add it to attribute sets where you'll need to hide prices.

Find all .phtml files where "prices & add to cart buttons" are (template > catalog > product > view.phtml, price.phtml, list.phtml, etc)

Paste this code Before the price code.

```
        <!-- Call For Price - begin -->
        <?php $attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('call_4_price'); ?>
            <?php $attribute_value = $attribute ->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); ?>
            <?php if ($attribute_value == 'Yes'): ?>
                //Please Call for pricing
            <?php else: ?>
```

And this after the add to cart button.

```
            <?php endif; ?>
        <!-- Call For Price - end -->
```

Answer (score 3):

Create an Yes/No attribute for Call For Price. When creating products, put something into the price field just to get past validation.

Now modify your template files to not show the price if it Call For Price is set to 'Yes'.